# Is it possible to access a function outside a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

```
const MainContainer = () => {

    const muuriRef = useRef();

    // Items state
    const [items_ig, setItems_ig] = useState(generateInstaContainer());
    const [items_fb, setItems_fb] = useState(generateFbContainer());
    const [items_twit, setItems_twit] = useState(generateTwitterContainer());

    // Items as children


    const children_ig = items_ig.map(({id, color, title, width, height}) => (
        <Item_IG
            id={id}
            key={id}
            color={color}
            title={title}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            remove={removeFunction_ig}
        />
    ));

    const children_fb = items_fb.map(({id, color, title, width, height}) => (
        <Item_FB
            id={id}
            key={id}
            color={color}
            title={title}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            remove={removeFunction_fb}
        />
    ));

    const children_twit = items_twit.map(({id, color, title, width, height}) => (
        <Item_TWIT
            id={id}
            key={id}
            color={color}
            title={title}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            remove={removeFunction_twit}
        />

    ));

    function addInstaGram() {
        setItems_ig(items_ig.concat(generateInstaContainer(1)));
    }

    function addFacebook() {
        setItems_fb(items_fb.concat(generateFbContainer(1)));
    }

    function addTwitter() {
        setItems_twit(items_twit.concat(generateTwitterContainer(1)));
    }

    // render
    return (
            <MuuriComponent
                options={{
                    layoutDuration: 400,
                    layoutEasing: "ease",
                    dragEnabled: true,
                    dragSortInterval: 50,
                    dragReleaseDuration: 400,
                    dragReleseEasing: "ease"
                }}
                ref={muuriRef}
            >
                {children_ig}
                {children_fb}
                {children_twit}
            </MuuriComponent>

            <div className="test"><Button
                onClickF={() => addFacebook()}
                onClickT={() => addTwitter()}
                onClickI={() => addInstaGram()}


            /></div>
    );
};

};
```

I want to use the `onClick` actions in another component, but I am unsure how to access the functions that would update the grid in this component. I thought about a callback function, but when I send this component and the newly created callback to the main index the button div is rendered twice because it's returned in the first instance. I'm still learning React, I'm mainly familiar with Python. Any help appreciated, thank you!

This is what I used for the callback function.

```
const Button = ({onClickI, onClickT, onClickF}) => {
    return ( <div className={someStyles}>
        <button onClick={onClickI}>Test 1</button>
        <button onClick={onClickT}>Test 3</button>
        <button onClick={onClickF}>Test 2</button>
    </div> )
```

Comment: *"I want to use the onClick actions in another component,"* these functions wouldn't make sense in other components, since they are specific to this component. I assume what you really mean is *"I want to trigger this behavior from other components"*. There are various ways to do this. One would be to lift the state up and actually have the functions be defined at a root component, so that they can be passed to any component that needs them. Or you can use a publish/subscriber system and have this component listen to events which are triggered by other components.

Comment: *"Is it possible to access a function outside a component in React?"* To answer the literal question: No. This has nothing to do with React, it's how lexical scope in JavaScript and other languages work. In Python you cannot access a variable that is defined inside a function outside of that function either (I forgot if you can define nested functions in Python, but if you can it's the same thing).

Comment: Okay that does make sense. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Can You try this

```
const Button = ({onClickI, onClickT, onClickF}) => {
        return ( <div className={someStyles}>
            <button onClick={() => onClickI()}>Test 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => onClickT()}>Test 3</button>
            <button onClick={() => onClickF()}>Test 2</button>
        </div> )
```

Comment: This would still make it render inside of the MainContainer component. I would like for it to be ignored there so I could place it elsewhere in the DOM or access the functions that are necessary to update the grid.

Comment: That's not in any way different than what the OP does. A function that only calls `f` is not different than `f` itself.